# "Failed to start Initial hibernation setup job" prevents EC2 start up

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-ec2

Whenever I stop and then restart an EC2 instance, it encounters this error:

```sh
[  OK  ] Mounted RPC Pipe File System.
[   92.832286] hibinit-agent[2507]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[   92.888343] hibinit-agent[2507]: File "/usr/bin/hibinit-agent", line 496, in <module>
[FAILED] Failed to start Initial hibernation setup job.
See 'systemctl status hibinit-agent.service' for details.
[   92.890244] hibinit-agent[2507]: main()
[   92.890838] hibinit-agent[2507]: File "/usr/bin/hibinit-agent", line 435, in main
[  OK  ] Started RPC bind service.
[   92.892552] hibinit-agent[2507]: if not hibernation_enabled(config.state_dir):
[  OK  ] Reached target rpc_pipefs.target.
[   92.893601] hibinit-agent[2507]: File "/usr/bin/hibinit-agent", line 390, in hibernation_enabled
[  OK  ] Reached target NFS client services.
[   92.895471] hibinit-agent[2507]: imds_token = get_imds_token()
[  OK  ] Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[   92.896838] hibinit-agent[2507]: File "/usr/bin/hibinit-agent", line 365, in get_imds_token
[  OK  ] Reached target Remote File Systems.
[   92.898610] hibinit-agent[2507]: response = requests.put(token_url, headers=request_header)
[   92.899534] hibinit-agent[2507]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 121, in put
[   92.899600] hibinit-agent[2507]: return request('put', url, data=data, **kwargs)
[   92.901303] hibinit-agent[2507]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packageWelcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
try again to boot into default mode.

Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.

Press Enter to continue.
```

The EC2 instance is an m5d.xlarge which is configured with the following user data script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -x
IDX=1
for DEV in /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Amazon_EC2_NVMe_Instance_Storage_*-ns-1; do
  mkfs.xfs ${!DEV}
  mkdir -p /local${!IDX}
  echo ${!DEV} /local${!IDX} xfs defaults,noatime 1 2 >> /etc/fstab
  IDX=$((${!IDX} + 1))
done
mount -a
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install git amazon-cloudwatch-agent jq -y
sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker
# service docker start
usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
chkconfig docker on
cd /local1
# followed by bootstrapping the application
```

The instance is running the latest version of Amazon Linux 2 and hosting a Neo4j server in a Docker container, so the user data installs Docker, starts the service and then pulls and runs the Neo4j container.

Is there something in the user data or elswhere that is causing the hibernation setup job to fail, specifically mounting the nvme storage perhaps?